# Automatically attaching to support behavior not completely successful

Tags: visual-studio-2010, resharper-5.1

I have a Visual Studio 2010 solution containing several C# projects, with Resharper 5.1 installed and enabled. All these projects target the .NET Framework 4.

This solution has been working fine for months, but this morning I got the following message when the solution was loaded:

[image: Visual Studio 2010 error]

I've looked around for an explanation on the meaning of this message, but with little luck.

Additionally, I haven't been able to repro this error, and it doesn't seem to have broken anything on my project.

Still, I don't like these kind of unexplained errors, so I was wondering if anyone reading this knows the root cause?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hmm, that's special.  It must be a debugger notification, the part of VS that 'attaches' and makes "Managed" a category.  The other category is "Unmanaged", a different kind of debugger interface.  It clearly lost its marbles there.

Counter-measures, in order, are:

1. Restart VS.
2. Reboot
3. Install Service Pack 1, it has many debugger fixes.

Consider moving 3 up the list if you haven't installed it yet, there are a ton of bug fixes and tweaks and works well.

Comment: Yeah, that's what I did, actually, and in that order :)

Comment: I've got the same problem and installing SP1 didin't help. Restarting VS helps some times (not always). Actually I have no problem about this, everything I need works, but the error message makes and the fact something is bad is itchy.

Answer (score 1):

In Visual Studio 2012 and Windows 8.1, I had this problem,I changed X86 from Solution Properties/Build/Platform target then my problem resolved.

Answer (score 1):

This has been nagging me for a while. Finally I found a solution.

When I press the help button they suggest I sort out the attached debug option. Without any result I finally managed to check the `Enable SQL Server Debugging` option under `Project Properties - Debug`.

Answer (score 0):

I have the exact same setting as you: VS2010 with several C# projects pointing to Net 4 and Resharper 5.1. I'm on Windows XP SP3
I was getting the exact same error, along with an empty VS icon in the taskbar.
The empty icon got away when I shifted VS to my main monitor (I have 2) and restarted. It seems that VS doesn't like to be in the second monitor.
As for your error, I cleaned up the Resharper cache (I'm storing it in the TEMP folder, not the solution folder) restarted, and didn't get the error again

Comment: I haven't seen this error for a while, so I'm not sure if this would be the solution, but I do have multiple monitors. I'll keep an eye out for a repro. Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

In Debug Menu - GoTo Solution Properties and select debug tab and tick the **ENABLE SQL SERVER DEBUGGING** checkbox